# SQL- Finding a gap that is x amount of months with the same foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I am editing this to clarify my question.

Let's say I have a table that holds patient information. I need to find new patients for this year, and the date of their prescription first prescription when they were considered new.  Anytime there is a six month gap they are considered a new patient.

How do I accomplish this using SQL.  I can do this in Java and any other imperative language easily enough, but I am having problems doing this in SQL.  I need this script to be run in Crystal by non-SQL users

```
    Table:

    Patient ID     Prescription Date
    -----------------------------------------
    1              12/31/16
    1              03/13/17
    2              10/10/16
    2              05/11/17
    2              06/11/17 
    3              01/01/17
    3              04/20/17
    4              01/31/16
    4              01/01/17 
    4              07/02/17
```

So Patients 2 and 4 are considered new patients. Patient 4 is considered a new patient twice, so I need dates for each time patient 4 was considered new 1/1/17 and 7/2/17. Patients 1 and 3 are not considered new this year.

So far I have the code below which tells me if they are new this year, but not if they had another six month gap this year.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     this_year.patient_id
    ,this_year.date

FROM (SELECT
         patient_id
        ,MIN(prescription_date) as date
      FROM table
      WHERE prescription_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2017-
      12-31 00:00:00.000'
      GROUP BY [patient_id]) AS this_year

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
         patient_id
        ,MAX(prescription_date) as date
      FROM table
      WHERE prescription_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-
      12-31 00:00:00.000' 
      GROUP BY [patient_id]) AS last_year         


WHERE DATEDIFF(month, last_year.date, this_year.date) > 6
OR last_year.date IS NULL
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter for patients where the max prescription date is greater than 6 months ago?  If so look into the [HAVING clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql).

Comment: Your description of the problem does not quite match what you state you expect. For example, patient 2 does NOT have a six month gap in the current year. Are all patients considered new at the beginning of the year? That would mean you could simply exclude those rows entirely? To be fair, none of your data has a 6 month gap in the current year.

Comment: How can data be returned at all if we're not even 6 months into the year? Something isn't making sense.

Comment: Yeah, something wasn't making sense... me.  I apologize. I was in a hurry to get to a meeting.   I should have reviewed what I posted before hitting send. I edited the question to add clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Patient 2 in your example does **not** meet the criteria you specified ... that being said ...

You can try something like this ... untested but should be similar (assuming you can put this in a stored procedure):

`WITH ordered AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Prescription Date]) rn
    FROM table1 
)
SELECT o1.[PatientID], DATEDIFF(s, o1.[Prescription Date], o2.[Prescription Date]) diff
  FROM ordered o1 JOIN ordered o2
    ON o1.rn + 1 = o2.rn 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(m, o1.[Prescription Date], o2.[Prescription Date]) > 6`

Replace `table1` with the name of your table.

Comment: To put it more simply, anytime there is a six month gap they are considered a new patient. I think that sums it up much better. I was in a hurry and should have watched how I formulated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean the patient has not been prescribed in the last 6 months.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM table_name 
WHERE prescribed_date >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

This gives you the list of users that have been prescribed in the last 6 months. You want the list of users that are not in this list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
                      FROM table_name 
                      WHERE prescribed_date >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()))
```

You'll need to amend the field and table names.